# Cannot upload image in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cannot upload image in Codeigniter.

It always show The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

My coding (Controller):

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('upload');
            $config['upload_path'] = "./public/uploadimg";
            $config['allowed_types'] = "*";
            $config['max_size'] = '10000';

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
            {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                echo $this->upload->data($config);
                //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
```

View :

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://192.1.100.1/site/test_image/upload/" method="post">
    <input type="file"  name="userfile" id="userfile"/><Br>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload">
</form>
```

Regards,

Comment: Are you sure you are showing us all the code? The only code path that triggers $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype'); is if is_allowed_filetype() returns false. According to the code sample you show us, allowed_types should be set to '*' and is_allowed_filetype should return TRUE on its first condition.

Comment: Yes that all my coding. so what should i do ?

Comment: You could try to modify Upload.php to add some debug output, like echoing allowed_types, making sure that it gets set to what you think, etc...

Comment: Which line should i change in upload.php?

Comment: Well an easy one would be to add (if you have the same version of CodeIgniter) at line 586 an echo $this->allowed_types to know what it contains (in public function is_allowed_filetype($ignore_mime = FALSE))

Comment: The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: This is clearly not an echo call you added to upload.php but the error message that code igniter reports.  You can check the source to see if your output happened before the actual page.

Comment: Dear, Can you tell me step to solve this problem?

Comment: Please consider my suggestions if you want me to help. I do not have you code and I cannot debug it remotely for you.

Comment: Do `var_dump($_FILES);` and see what you get.

Comment: array(1) { ["userfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "1.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(38) "D:\pc1\wamp\tmp\php7636.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(39599) } }

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your allowed types explicitly. I remember having the same problem before.

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'docx|pdf|doc|gif|jpg|png|tiff';
```

Comment: I tried already but not working. show The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed..

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using? I tried your code with a png file and $config['allowed_types'] = 'png'; and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); 
       if($this->input->post('upload')){ //submit name           

        $config['upload_path'] = "./public/uploadimg";
        $config['allowed_types'] = "png|jpg|jpeg";
        $config['max_size'] = '10000';
        $config['max_width'] = '1000';
        $config['max_height'] = '800';

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
        else{
            echo $this->upload->data($config);
            //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
        }
```

And make sure that your action  url is right. sorry i'm bad at English.